# Produce automated suggestions on beancount entries

Tags: predictive-models, tensorflow, finance

I'm doing text-based, double-entry bookkeeping using beancount, and I'm creating a GUI application using node.js to automate some steps in the process.

Some example data looks as follows:

| Payee #1 | Narration #2 | Date #3 | Account #4 | Other account #5 | Amount #6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Employer | Salary payment | 2023-03-25 | Assets:Bankaccount | Income:Salary | 1000.00 |
| Real estate company | Apartment rent | 2023-04-01 | Expenses:Rent | Assets:Bankaccount | 700.00 |
| Supermarket | Groceries | 2023-04-20 | Expenses:Groceries | Assets:Bankaccount | 150.00 |

Having roughly 10'000 such items completely available, I thought about using machine learning or a similar approach to predict some values I have to otherwise provide manually.

Always having available are: Payee (1), Narration (2), Date (3), Amount (6).
What I would like to predict/make suggestions for: Account (4) and Other account (5).

Ideally, the result would be a function predicting those elements.

I've looked into tensorflow, but I believe the challenge here is to convert the strings into meaningful numbers that can in turn be mapped to a range between 0 and 1 (does this even make sense?).

The payee can sometimes be similar, but is not always reported exactly the same. The narration will be provided manually by me anyway. The date and amount could easily be converted to numerical values. Account and Other account are categorical data which could easily be mapped to an index - there are roughly 150 different ones.

Any idea of how to tackle this? Is using an engine like tensorflow (or similar) even a sensible approach? I think the task at hand is not too complex, I just don't really know where to get started without hand-coding everything from scratch.

I had this question stackoverflow, where it was closed as off-topic, which is why I'm trying again here.